# Django ORM - filter method with some arithmetic calculation

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following query which I am trying to turn into a django ORM query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE discontinued = 0 AND ((unitsinstock + unitsonorder) < reorderlevel)
```

I tried the following python code but with no success.

```py
products = Products.objects.filter(
    discontinued=0, (unitsinstock + unitsonorder < reorderlevel)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`F() expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) and the [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation) function found within the ORM. It will allow you to do what you want to do.

```py
products = Products.objects.filter(discontinued=0).annotate(
    currentlevel=Sum(F("unitsinstock") + F("unitsonorder"))
).filter(reorderlevel__gt=F("currentlevel"))
```

Answer (score 1):

F() expression helped to solve this,
Below query worked perfectly

```
Products.objects.filter(
  discontinued =0, 
  reorderlevel__gt = F("unitsinstock") + F("unitsonorder")
)
```